# Arelle locate ratio extraction command that i cannot understand to find in docs(~2pages)

Tags: c, python-3.x, cmd, xbrl, arelle

The basic command while we are working with [Command Line Operation in Arelle is](http://arelle.org/documentation/command-line-operation/):

```
python arelleCmdLine.py arguments
```

provided we go with the `cmd` to the `folder` that arelle is installed.

I have devoted huge resources but i cannot find if there is a command in the [Documentation](http://arelle.org/documentation/command-line-operation/) (about ~2 pages) that can output ratios (e.g. Current Ratio) or metrics (e.g. Revenue) instead of having to download all the data in Columns and filter the data. I must admit that i cannot understand some commands in the documentation.

What i am doing to download data is:

```
python arelleCmdLine.py -f http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1009672/000119312514065056/crr-20131231.xml -v --facts D:\Save_in_File.html --factListCols "Label Name contextRef unitRef Dec Prec Lang Value EntityScheme EntityIdentifier Period Dimensions"
```

- `-f` is the command that pulls data and after that is a location with `data` in the web
- `-v` is the command to validate the `data` that are pulled
- `--facts` Saves the data in an `HTML` file in a designated `directory`
- `factListCols` is the `Columns` i choose to have (i take all the available columns in the upper command).

*There is an absolute zero on tutorials.*

Arelle only runs on `Python 3` and can be downloaded without creating a hassle only by following [these quick and simple steps.](http://arelle.org/documentation/running-from-source/)